# Constrain unique_together could have conflict with the unique_field in dajngo Class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-constraints

I would like to know if there is any conflict using the constraint `unique_together` as well as the parameter `unique=true` in one of the fields that belong to the array of the `unique_together`.

I can´t remove the parameter `unique=true` of my field because it´s used as a the foreign key in another model.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  # User information
  fiscal_number = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ['fiscal_number', 'email']
```

As you can see the goal is to make the combination of the fields `fiscal_number` and `email` unique.

Comment: If you set `unique=True` for `fiscal_number`, it makes no sense that it is also part of a `unique_together` .

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, I would like to know if there is any conflict using the constrain unique_together as well as the parameter `unique=true` in one of the fields that belong to the array of the `unique_together`.

**It makes no sense**. Indeed, by setting `unique=True` it means that there can't be two users with the same `fiscal_number`, unless if these two users are the same user.

The `unique_together = ['fiscal_year', 'email']` means that the *combination* of a `fiscal_year` and an `email` has to be unique. That means that there can't be two users where both the `fiscal_year` and the `email` are the same (unless these two users are the same user). But since we already made `fiscal_year` as a field unique, we already know that this can not happen.

You can mark the `email` field as `unique=True` as well. This is *not* equivalent to `unique_together = ['fiscal_number', 'email']`. With `unique_together`, the combination of the two columns should be unique, whereas setting `unique=True` on multiple fields, means that all `User`s have a different `fiscal_year`, and a different `email`, etc.

Comment: yeah you are right.  But if i only set the **fiscal_number** with the parameter **unique=true** could happen that many **fiscal_number** have the same email and that´s what I need to avoid, because I have to make that every **fiscal_number** be unique and also has a unique **email**, that´s why I thought to use the **unique_together** constraint. Or do you thing that there is another way to solve it ?

Comment: @user15854983: you can make `email` unique as well. But the `unique_together` here is *implied* by the fact that the `fiscal_number` is already unique.

Comment: oh yes, I also thought that but I didn´t know that was possible, to have two fields unique. I´m going to try bro, thank you